# Help transform this description into a concise sentence

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, sentence-construction

I need to create a concise sentence, with as few words as possible (below 7 if possible) from the following description:

> Our program will only process files that are newer than 6 months old.

I need to transform it into a sentence, where the **'6 months'** must be written after a colon. Below is a sentence that I've managed to come up with but still sounds (a bit?) off.

> Maximum backdate of file processing: 6 months

I am not sure if the whole sentence even make sense at all, but what I would like to focus on is the word **'backdate'**. I looked up the word's meaning but it doesn't seem like it means what I've previously thought. So this sentence might actually not deliver the intended meaning at all.

Comment: Could you clarify what your constraints are? Do you need to use the word ‘backdate’ in the sentence?

Comment: The only constraint is that the words '6 months' need to be written after a colon. The word 'backdate' doesn't need to be included, it was just an example of a more concise sentence I can think of.

Comment: "Maximum file age: 6 months." It's a phrase, not a sentence (like your example). I don't think you can fit a colon into an actual sentence without a couple of clauses.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty this is exactly what I need! Thank you! Can you write it as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: OK, Grandevox, I just copied the comment verbatim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Maximum file age: 6 months."

It's a phrase, not a sentence (like your example). I don't think you can fit a colon into an actual sentence without a couple of clauses